# What is the time complexity of the following code snippet?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have written the following code snippet to find the range summaries, i.e., when given a sorted integer array without any duplicates, it returns the summaries as:

```
/* IP: [0,1,2,4,5,7]
 * OP: ["0->2","4->5","7"]
 */

class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> summaryRanges(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<string> res;

        if(nums.empty())
            return res;

        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) {
            int lowerRange=nums[i];

            while(((i+1)<nums.size()) && (nums[i+1]-nums[i]==1))
                i++;

            int higherRange=nums[i];

            if(lowerRange!=higherRange) {
                string str=to_string(lowerRange)+"->"+to_string(higherRange);
                res.push_back(str);
            } else
                res.push_back(to_string(lowerRange));
        }

        return res;
    }
};
```

I am wondering about the time complexity of the above code snippet.  In my opinion, I am doing some "task" (execution of the inner while loop) for each element in the array (using the outer for loop).  Due to this, in the worst case, the complexity should be O(n^2) in my opinion.  On the other hand, I am doubtful because I do `i++` in the inner while loop, due to which, I won't do the "task" on *all* the elements using the outer for loop.  Due to this increment, I am visiting all the elements only once in my entire code.  So, this should make the complexity O(n).  Could someone please confirm if the complexity is O(n^2) or O(n)?

Comment: I think you're correct. The inner loop advances the index of the outer loop, so it's really like just one loop.

Comment: @Ramesh I was a little to fast to comment. Linear is the correct answer :)

Comment: @Barmar, but then in the worst case, inner while loop (which might access all the elements) will be executed for each element by the outer for loop.  So, wouldn't it be `O(n^2)` then?

Comment: @Ramesh No, because if the inner loop accesses all the elements, the out er loop will stop immediately.

Comment: Re, "I am doing some 'task' (execution of the inner while loop) for each element in the array."  No, because the inner loop and the outer both increment the same variable.  Your function only scans the array one time from beginning to end.  It could be re-written as a single loop if you added some state variables.

Comment: Any elements accessed by the inner loop are skipped by the outer loop. Together they just access all the elements once.

Comment: @Barmar, I got you.  Thank you.  Kindly put it as an answer, so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the inner loop advances the same iteration variable as the outer loop, any elements accessed by the inner loop are skipped by the outer loop. Together they just access each element once. So that makes it `O(n)`.

In terms of time-complexity, it's like a loop with an `if` statement in it:

```
for (i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
    if ((i+1)<nums.size()) && (nums[i+1]-nums[i]==1)) {
        //
    } else {
        //
    }
}
```

Writing it this way would require different logic to determine when to update `lowerRange` and `higherRange`.

Comment: Sorry, I had to accept @T33C's answer since it appears to be more elaborate.  I wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 0):

You're advancing in your inner loop, hence it runs in O(n) time complexity.